# AMP form validation for Safari

Tags: javascript, validation, safari, amp-html

AMP form only allows me to use HTML5 form validation to validate users inputs. It works well in desktop Chrome browser. But Safari couldn't support HTML5 form validation until now. I found solution, requires external Javascript to implement form validation on Safari browser. But in my case, AMP doesn't allow me to do so.

> Is there any hacks or trick to bypass HTML5 validation inputs for Safari?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try comparing your AMP document to the [AMP by Example `amp-form` demo](https://ampbyexample.com/playground/#url=https%3A%2F%2Fampbyexample.com%2Fcomponents%2Famp-form%2Fsource%2F). The `amp-form` extension implements a form validation API polyfill for browsers that don't support native validation. If you're using `amp-form` in Safari versions without native support, the polyfill behavior should run automatically.

The polyfill validation should look something like this:
[image: An example of the amp-form polyfill validation UI. There is a text bubble saying "value missing" pointing to a text field labeled "Name..." above a "Subscribe" button.]

Answer (score 0):

It was mentioned in this [HTML5 documentation](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/forms/constraintvalidation/#toc-safari) that:

> Even though Safari supports the constraint validation API, as of this writing (version 6), Safari will not prevent submission of a form with constraint validation issues.
>
> The easiest way around this is to use the same approach as the workaround described above, give all forms the `novalidate` attribute and manually prevent form submissions using `preventDefault`.

With this, you may want to check this [thread](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/issues/3343) wherein it gives guidelines regarding AMP Forms Support and also issues to track such as [Forms should respect the `novalidate` attribute](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/issues/3469). View given codes [here](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/pull/3543/commits/0a59b72b6e20e596cf5967b7b7642dcc458da8c7) and see it will help you.